# Showing this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My sp is

```
EXEC _REPORTS @StartDate=N'17-Sep-2016',
    @EndDate=N'17-Sep-2016',
    @CustomerID=0,
    @ProductID=0,
    @BranchID=0,
    @NumberOfRecords=100,
    @PageNo=1,
    @IsBuy=1
```

here the region of date used in where

```
 AND FCSB.FCBuySellDate 
 BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate,105) AND  CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate,105)
```

Comment: I dont think error is generated from that `where` clause

Comment: if i comment this line the procedure will work fine for me but if i use , it shows the error

Comment: What is the datatype of `FCBuySellDate`

Comment: datetime  is the datatype

Comment: Then remove the convert `..FCSB.FCBuySellDate between @StartDate and @EndDate..`

Comment: no same error occurs

Comment: The format you are sending is implicitly convertable not sure why you are getting that error. Can you change the input format to this `2016-09-17`

Comment: same error occured

Comment: That is impossible can you show the full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123588/discussion-between-john-walker-and-prdp).

Comment: Remove the `convert` function in `Where` clause and pass the input in this format `2016-09-17`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is primarily you are getting some wrong formatted data to convert, For example

```
 declare @StartDate nvarchar(15) = N'17-Septt-2016'

 select CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate,105)
```

You will get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If you get correct date you get it converted, one way to ignore this error is to do TRY_CONVERT which willl return NULL. Best way to solve this problem is to identify why it is getting wrong date as parameter and fix that.

```
select TRY_CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate,105)
```

Comment: if date is null it should show all details , id date provided that particular date data should be shown –

Answer (score 0):

check for null value in FCSB.FCBuySellDate. It might be cause of an error

try this

```
AND FCSB.FCBuySellDate BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate,105) AND  CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate,105) 
AND isnull(FCSB.FCBuySellDate,'') <> ''
```

Also try this, convert column in datetime

```
AND CONVERT(datetime,FCSB.FCBuySellDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,@StartDate,105) AND  CONVERT(datetime,@EndDate,105)
```

Comment: if date is null it should show all details , id date provided that particular date data should be shown

Comment: convert table column into date time. It must be a problem with data in that column.